# VB Search for a pattern in a filename

Tags: vb.net, file, search

I am trying to make a simple search engine that will search for a pattern in a file name e.g. a number that is a part of a file name. So far it only searches for the exact string e.g. `o2.url`, but I have `o21.url` and `o22.url` in the same folder and I would like to be able to have those in my search results. I want to ask is there any way of modifying this code to achieve that.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
    "C:\Users\GrzegoP\Desktop\xxx", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, Text1.Text & ".url")

            List1.Items.Add(foundFile)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the "*" wildcard:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
    "C:\Users\GrzegoP\Desktop\xxx", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*" & Text1.Text & "*" & ".url")
```

This code finds any file, with the .url extension, including `Text1.Text` in any part of its name.

Comment: Works... Sometimes I forget about simple solutions... Thanks

Comment: @Saint No problem. Simple solutions are the most easily forgettable ones :)